# (TableLayout)findViewById( null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-layout, null, android-tablelayout

I  search for answer all day long, but when i try to get the table layout i am having null. 
I found info that it may be another table layout with same name, but there is only one.
My .xml file :

[my xml](http://filebin.ca/A1sZlhzeV0b)

and my code is here `layout6 = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.shdslResultsTableLayout);
        layout6.setVisibility(0);`

always ends up with null pointer.
Please help.

Comment: seems it is unable to locate your view. Have you called setContentView to set the view to your xml layout file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `findViewById()` is returning a  NPE, try some of these:

- Clean the project via Project -> Clean... -> check your project -> OK
- Ensure you have absolutely no spelling errors in the ID
- Make sure the contentView is displaying the correct layout where the `TableLayout` exists
- Make sure you `setContentView` before `findViewById`

I'm assuming the 3rd option I've listed is most likely your problem.

Re-cleaning the project may also help after each of these steps.

Answer (score 4):

Please make sure you call the right layout in the `setContentView` method, and make sure you call `setContentView` BEFORE calling `findViewById`.

If you made that, then try to clean / rebuild.

Hope this will help you